# Ajax post to php on same page not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to pass a var from jQuery to PHP.

After researching I found the most common suggestion was to do this with `Post` with Ajax and store the post var using PHP.

My PHP skills are pretty good but I can't say the same about my JavaScript skills.

This is what I am doing but does not seem to work at all:

```
  // jquery libray included etc etc
  <script>
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://currentpage.com",
      data: "var=value",
      dataType: string
    });
 </script>
 </head>


<body>

<?php
if($_REQUEST["var"] == "value") {
    echo "var passed and stored";
}
?>
```

Comment: datatype should be "text"

Comment: `$.ajax()` has both a success and error method, add them both and put an alert in each to see what is executed and if you do have some errors.

Comment: What do you get when you go to http://currentpage.com?var=value

Comment: If you send your ajax request to the same page, you get all the content as response (<head><script>... etc included) . I guess that is not what you really want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script>
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {var:'value'},
      dataType: 'text',
      success:function(data){
       // Test what is returned from the server
         alert(data);
      }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: I just tried this, I also tried changing the dataType to text in your example as suggested above, but it didn't work. The php is still not echoing out the message that it should on post. I know that php is ran on the server, do i need to add a refresh too?

Comment: @TheApptracker: did you enclose the value inside ''? I updated to 'value' in the example

Comment: Yes i used the exact example you currently have present `data: "{var:'value'}",`

Comment: That also does not work. I've changed my php to `echo "hello world"` on any `$_POST` regardless of vars set yet, just for testing, it still doesn't work. Should php be picking this up or does it need a refresh call?

Comment: @TheApptracker: i quite believe that you have cross domain issue. When you use absolute paths, some browsers think that it's a cross domain request (even you're not performing cross domain request).

Comment: @TheApptracker: try with a relative path instead.

Comment: i've just tried with the current page name only, `index.php` and it does not seem to work. A `form` works perfectly, so i know the php is ok and the path is ok.

Comment: @TheApptracker: did you check that the request reached the server? You're performing ajax request. But I did not see where you get the response data and display it on the page. Check out my updated answer for more details. (remember to use relative paths as some browsers block requests with absolution paths)

Comment: The alert is returning the `var` but also the entire page code too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31476/discussion-between-khanh-to-and-theapptracker)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script>
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://currentpage.com",
      data: {variablename:'value'},
      dataType: "text", //Available types xml, json, script, html, jsonp, text
      success:function(response){
       //Returned from server
       alert(response);
      }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: I just tried this also but nothing seems to but it didn't work. The php is still not echoing out the message that it should on post.

Comment: What is the name of the variable you are passing? Is it var? Replace variablename with testvariable and In your server replace with this code `if($_REQUEST["testvariable"] == "value") {
    echo "var passed and stored";
}`

Comment: try `if($_POST["testvariable"] == "value"){ echo "hello world";}` don't forget to change `data:{testvariable:'value'}`

Comment: also check your console or network tab in chrome developers tool whether the request rached the server. `shift+ctrl+I`

Comment: I get this in the console `send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) htc.sx:10
e.resolveWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C`

Comment: what is displayed when you submit the ajax request?

Comment: i have the ajax request within `$('document').ready(function(){` so it should be sent on page load. I have set an alert on success and it alerts fine. I think the ajax request is fine but the url does not change in my address bar and the php does not act.

Comment: In ajax request, the url will not change in address bar. Data will be sent to the specified url and the response form the url(php script) is captured and can be handled in the present displayed page. Roughly put, to send or fetch contents from another page without refresh or re-directing from the current page is made possible by ajax. You can track your sent data and received response in `network` tab available in chrome developer tool.