# Php code instead of data in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this ajax code, pretty simple :

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "save.php",
         data: {
         imgBase64: dataURL,
         counter : time
         }
       });
```

And in the other side, I have my php file :

```
<?php
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'upload/');
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$counter = $_POST['counter'];
$formatedcounter = sprintf('%03d', $counter);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$filename = UPLOAD_DIR . 'GWD' .  $formatedcounter . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($filename, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

I would like to combine both. Is it possible to write the php code instead of "save.php" for data in ajax? I've already tried but I get errors in phpstorm.

Thanks a lot!
Regards.

Comment: No it's not possible..thats not how ajax works... `url:"you must provide an url here"`

Comment: Can't see where `$file` is defined in the php file

Comment: @BilalJohn ok. Thanks a lot. So second question : is it possible to right the php code after the ajax and point the url to this piece of code, which is not in a separate file?

Comment: @PhilippeGREBAN yeah its possible. To send ajax request to the same page you can keep url parameter empty

Comment: this example might help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561569/jquery-ajax-passing-value-on-php-same-page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007597/ajax-post-to-php-on-same-page-not-working

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna read this. Thanks for helping a beginner <3

Comment: "To send ajax request to the same page you can keep url parameter empty" You can do this certainly, but it's usually considered a poor separation of concerns. If you keep the PHP separate then you can use it from lots of different web pages, not just one. Then you have some useful re-usable code for receiving file uploads. Just my opinion though, you can use whatever design suits you.

Comment: I understand and I agree. It's more structured. I was just wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys.

So it can only point to a file. It's not (for example) possible to write the php code after and to point to it.

Comment: you can write both on same page.. see above comments... may be read this too http://makitweb.com/how-to-handle-ajax-request-on-the-same-page-php/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051548/ajax-to-php-on-the-same-page

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna read this. Thanks for helping a beginner <3